Solving the recursion $ \kappa_n=\frac{2 \pi}{n} \kappa_{n-2} $, with $\kappa_1=2, \kappa_2=\pi$
For the recursion $$
\kappa_n=\frac{2 \pi}{n} \kappa_{n-2}
$$
with $\kappa_1=2, \kappa_2=\pi$, the solution should be
$$
\kappa_n=\frac{\pi^{n / 2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)} \quad(n \geq 1)
$$
is there a general method to solve this?

Yes, there is a general method using generating functions, see for example this post.

The easiest way to proceed is proving by induction. For $n=3$, the general expression equals the recursive case
\begin{align}
\kappa_3&=\frac{\pi^{3/2}}{\Gamma(\frac{3}{2}+1)}=\frac{\pi^{3/2}}{\frac{3}{2}\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})}\\
&=\frac{\pi^{3/2}}{\frac{3}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}=\frac{\pi^{3/2}}{\frac{3}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}\pi^{1/2}}\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{3}2=\frac{2\pi}{3}\kappa_1
\end{align}
Similar procedure follows for the $n=4$ case. Now the induction step. Let the general expression hold for $n\geq1$. From the recursion formula, one proceeds as
\begin{align}
\kappa_{n+2}&=\frac{2\pi}{n+2}\kappa_n=\frac{\pi}{\frac{n+2}{2}}\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+1)}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{\frac{n}{2}+1}\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+1)}=\frac{\pi^{\frac{n+2}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+1+1)}\\
&=\frac{\pi^{\frac{n+2}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{n+2}{2}+1)}
\end{align}
Thus the proof is complete. Note that use have been made of the following results
\begin{gather}
\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}\\
\Gamma(n+1)=n\Gamma(n)
\end{gather}

Making the problem more general
$$\kappa_n=\frac{a}{n} \kappa_{n-2}\qquad \text{with}\quad \kappa_1=b~,~\kappa_2=c$$ for $(a,b,c)$ all positive, by induction, you could show that
$$\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)\kappa_n=2^{-\frac{n}{2}-2} \,a^{\frac{n}{2}-1} \Big(4 c
   \left(1+(-1)^n\right)+b\sqrt{2 \pi a }   
   \left(1-(-1)^n\right)\Big)$$
which simplify a lot if, as in your case, $\large c=\frac{b}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi a}{2}} $. In such a case
$$\kappa_n=\frac {b\,\sqrt{\pi }\,  a^{\frac{n-1}{2}} } {2^{\frac{n+1}{2}}\,\,\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right) }$$
